# Groupby and join values but keep all columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I've this Dataframe and want to group on ID and join the values.

```
ID  | A_Num | I_Num
--------------------------
001 | A_001 | I_001
002 | A_002 | I_002
003 | A_003 | I_004
005 | A_002 | I_002
```

Desired Output

```
ID      | A_Num | I_Num
--------------------------
001     | A_001 | I_001
002;005 | A_002 | I_002
003     | A_003 | I_004
```

Code:

```
    df = df.groupby(['A_Num','I_Num'])['ID'].apply(lambda tags: ';'.join(tags))
    df.to_csv('D:\joined.csv', sep=';', encoding='utf-8-sig', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, index=False, header=True)
```

When I write the DataFrame to a csv file I've only the ID column.

Comment: You are selecting the `ID` column here `df = df.groupby(['A_Num','I_Num'])['ID']`

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand what you mean

Comment: `df.groupby(['A_Num','I_Num'])['ID'].apply(';'.join).reset_index().reindex(columns=df.columns).to_csv(...)` to maintain original column order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `reset_index()`:

```py
df=df.groupby(['A_Num','I_Num'])["ID"].apply(lambda tags: ';'.join(tags.values)).reset_index()
```

This way your aggregation from `apply()` will be executed, and then reassigned as `column` instead of `index`.

Answer (score 0):

Just another way to do it is:

```
result= df.groupby(['A_Num', 'I_Num']).agg({'ID': list})
result.reset_index(inplace=True)
result[['ID', 'A_Num', 'I_Num']]
```

The output is:

```
Out[37]: 
             ID    A_Num   I_Num
0        [001 ]   A_001    I_001
1  [002 , 005 ]   A_002    I_002
2        [003 ]   A_003    I_004
```

ID contains lists in that case. If you rather want strings, just do:

```
result['ID']= result['ID'].map(lambda lst: ';'.join(lst))
result[['ID', 'A_Num', 'I_Num']]
```

Which outputs:

```
Out[48]: 
        ID  A_Num  I_Num
0      001  A_001  I_001
1  002;005  A_002  I_002
2      003  A_003  I_004
```

Answer (score 0):

Groupby 'A_Num' and 'I_Num' and then merge the IDs in the same groups.

```
df.groupby(['A_Num','I_Num']).ID.apply(lambda x: ';'.join(x.tolist())).reset_index()
```